# Using composer with wordpress in docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, composer-php, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm try to setup a docker workspace with Alpine, PHP, Apache, MySQL and Composer.

Currently I'm trying to use the following images:

**PHP, Alpine and Composer:** https://hub.docker.com/r/petehouston/docker-alpine-php-composer/

**Wordpress:** https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

I created a **docker-compose.yml** file to manage this dependencies for me.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - ./www:/var/www/html
     links:
       - db
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

   alpine:
     image: petehouston/docker-alpine-php-composer:latest
     links:
       - wordpress
```

So my problem is I'm trying to use the composer of the alpine container to manager my Wordpress in the wordpress container but when i try to use the following command:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/www -w /wordpress/var/www/html composer/composer create-project roots/sage your-theme-name 8.5.0
```

nothing happens, and the alpine container doesn't stay up, after i run `compose-docker.up` he exits

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to `Wordpress container` from `Alpine container` using `-w /wordpress/var/www/html`.
As far as I understand, image `petehouston/docker-alpine-php-composer:latest` provides PHP deployment environment. That means you should use this image instead of `wordpress image`. 
Your compose file can be like

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   alpine:
     image: petehouston/docker-alpine-php-composer:latest
     volumes:
       - ./www:/home
     links:
       - db
     ports:
      - "8000:80"
     command: composer require phpunit/phpunit
     restart: always
```

Plz give me feedback. I'm sorry because i can't comment to get more information from you. Should you still get errors, comment here. I'll recheck

Comment: Hey there, man your answer is awesome. The only thins is that the alpine container keeps dying and restarting again, is there a way to leave him always up? so I can use composer to work with Wordpress inside him

Comment: PS: there were only 1 error in your code, It should be `ports: - "8000:80"`

Comment: if i try to run `docker exec -t -i stack_alpine_1 bash` to open the terminal and try to use composer, I get this `Error response from daemon: Container f9d60f6fcbba4b29bb31cda384f8390af385d5b786794135faa89a92d2bb3560 is restarting, wait until the container is running`

Comment: Thank you for fixing my file. I have just edited it. After that, I can start my cluster normally.

Comment: plz use docker ps to get <container id> or recheck you container name :/

Comment: I checked, says that the container is restarting... when I run the `docker-compose up` without the `-d` I can see him exiting.. actually I don't even need the alpine container. I just need a container with Composer running so I can install dependencies in my project anytime I want